# Groovy read file line by line and store it into list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I have a file called **apps.txt** which has three app names in it

frontendapp

authorizationservice

connectorservice*

In jenkins pipeline i want to perform some operation on them one by one so i am trying to get them in groovy list using this code -

```
                    list = readFile.readFileLineByLine("${workspace}/apps.txt").collect {it}
                    for (item in list) {
                        println "I need to perform some operations on files"
                    }
```

But getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException.
If i use file class like this - `list = new File("${workspace}/apps.txt").collect {it}` then it search for a file on Jenkins master node only and i get fileNotFoundException.

If i use `list = readFile("${workspace}/apps.txt").collect {it}` then list gets values character by character. How i can get app names from apps.txt inorder to perform operation on each app.

Comment: `def list = readFile("${workspace}/apps.txt").readLines()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempts are close, but mix things up.

Those are working ways:

```
def list = new File("${workspace}/apps.txt").text.readLines()
```

Note the `.text` call inbetween.

```
def list = readFile("${workspace}/apps.txt").readLines()
```

Or with the helper Jenkins provides.

Side note: `.collect{it}` is just `.collect()` - and usually is only
needed to copy a list.  Since the read lines from the file are already
eagerly read, those are copies.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me in a windows worker

```
script {
       def list = readFile("filesChanged").readLines()
       for(item in list){
          print item
          bat('type '+item) 
          }    
        }
```